# model mvc in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I work in projet which is developed in ruby on rails

I have this line :

```
 _orig_account     = Account.find_ussd_by_login_and_pass_and_type_and_name(_orgin,_pin,Account::Type::Creova.to_sym,_orgin)
```

honestly I didn't understand this code

I have another code :

```
 _resul   = PMClient.new.user_login_ussd(_orgin,_pin)
```

in this case user_login_ussd  is a function in the model specialy in : PMClient

the source code of **Account** is

```
class Account < CreovaBase

  attr :login, true
  attr :admin_login, true
  attr :admin_pass, true
  attr :type
  attr :name, true
  attr :status
  attr :balance, true
  attr :currency
  attr :dob, true
  attr :bank_id, true
  attr :routing, true
  attr :legal_name, true
  attr :bank_name, true
  attr :attribute, true
  attr :linker_id, true


  Status = Enum.new(:Enabled, :Suspended,:Deleted, :Legal_Hold, ['Enabled','Suspended','Deleted','Legal Hold'])

  Type = Enum.new(:Creova, :Bank, :Credit,:rt, ['Creova','Bank','Credit','rt'])


  Banks = Enum.new(:None, :Test1,:Test2 , :Test3, :Test4,
    ['','Test1','Test2','Test3','Test4'])

  def initialize(params=nil)
    super
  end

  def type=(val)
    val.blank? ? @type = nil : @type = val.to_sym
  end

  def status=(val)
    val.blank? ? @status = nil : @status = val.to_sym 
  end

  def currency=(val)
    val.blank? ? @currency = nil : @currency = val.to_sym
  end

  # should check that the account number either:
  # a) exists in the system
  # b) is a valid mobile number
  # c) ?? is a valid email address ??
  # returns [valid,message]
  def self.is_valid_account?(name, purpose=:send)
    #STUB
    return true
  end


  def formatted_balance(currency = :tnd)
    curr = Currency.get_currency(currency) rescue Currency.get_currency(:tnd)
    curr.display(balance.to_i)  
  end

  def formal_name(currency=:tnd)
    curr = Currency.get_currency(currency) rescue Currency.get_currency(:tnd)
    curr.formal_name
  end

  def save!

    #pmac = CreovaBase._get_admin()

    if @new_record
      # create_account will raise an exception if it cannot be created
      vars = self.instance_variables.map() { |v| v.sub('@','') unless ['@errors','@new_record'].include?(v) }.compact 
      params = {}
      vars.each() do |v|
        if self.send(v).is_a?(Enum::Member)
          params[v] = self.send(v).to_sym
        else
          params[v] = self.send(v)
        end
      end
      if PMClient.new.create_account(params)
        @new_record = false
      else
        raise 'account save failed'
      end
    else
      PMClient.new.update_account(admin_login,admin_pass,type,name,status)
    end
  end

  def save
    save!
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume your question is "what does this code do ?" (you may want to precise it, both in the title and question text).

```
 _orig_account     = Account.find_ussd_by_login_and_pass_and_type_and_name(_orgin,_pin,Account::Type::Creova.to_sym,_orgin)
```

Without any other info, I would suppose :

- This is a finder method that search and return Account from the database. Having [finder querie](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)s as class methods on the model is something very standard in Rails, with many provided "out of the box".
- The parameters match the various "and", with origin being the login and also the name (the two are probably the same in this case), then a password and a type (given as a [Symbol](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/symbols.htm#_What_can_symbols_do_for_you), another Ruby common practice).

The second part :

```
_resul   = PMClient.new.user_login_ussd(_orgin,_pin)
```

Is simply the creation of a PMClient object (PMClient.new), immediatly followed by a method call on the newly created object (".user_login_ussd"), giving two parameters.

Hope this helps.